# How to clear the autocomplete's input in Material-ui after an onChange?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

In the hooks version of [material UI](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/) I can't seem to be able to clear the autocomplete after an onChange event:

```
// @flow
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./Autocomplete.scss";
import AutocompleteUI from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

function Autocomplete(props) {
    const { options } = props;
    const [value, setValue] = useState();

    const container = useRef();
    const input = useRef();

    function onChange(event, newValue) {
        if (!newValue) return;
        props.onChange(newValue);
        setValue(undefined);
        input.current.value = "";
        event.target.value = "";
    }

    function renderInput(params) {
        return (
            <TextField
                inputRef={input}
                {...params}
                inputProps={{
                    ...params.inputProps,
                    autoComplete: "disabled", // disable autocomplete and autofill
                }}
                margin="none"
                fullWidth
            />
        );
    }

    return (
        <div className="Autocomplete-container">
            {value}
            <AutocompleteUI
                ref={container}
                options={options}
                autoHightlight={true}
                clearOnEscape={true}
                autoSelect={true}
                // freeSolo={true}
                getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
                renderInput={renderInput}
                value={value}
                onChange={onChange}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Autocomplete;
```

Diving into the [source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui-lab/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js) I've noticed the component uses [useAutocomplete](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui-lab/src/useAutocomplete/useAutocomplete.js) hook internally. However, neither **setInputValue** nor **resetInputValue** which live internally inside that hook are exposed outside. Is there a way to accomplish an input clear after an onChange?

Comment: By clear the autocomplete, do you mean simply empty the input box, or remove the suggestions?

Comment: @ChrisB. Yes, the former, I am trying to clear the input box.

Comment: Apparently it only works with refs, which is an idiotic design for a reusable React component in my opinion. You'd have to set the value directly on the DOM element, but I'm not familiar with their API.

Comment: @ChrisB. I have tried working with refs and changing the input's value directly, however as the component itself holds the state (via the useAutocomplete hook) it does not work

Comment: I am facing the same issue now. Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 9):

> You need to set the inputValue prop to your valueState and on onhange function just clear the valueState

```
<Autocomplete

inputValue={valueState}

onChange={(value, option) =>
{


    setOptions([])
    setValueState("")

}}

renderInput={params => (
    <TextField
        dir="rtl"
        onChange={(event) =>
        {

            setValueState(event.target.value)

        }}
        {...params}
        label="Search Patient"
        variant="filled"

        InputProps={{
            ...params.InputProps,
            endAdornment: (
                <React.Fragment>
                    {loading ? (
                        <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} />
                    ) : null}
                    {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                </React.Fragment>
            )
        }}
    />
)}
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and I solved it with this :

```
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
```

...

```
     <Autocomplete
          id="grouped-demo"
          options={tagsList}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option.tag}
          onChange={(event, value) =>value ? setSearch(value.tag) : setSearch(event.target.value)}
          style={{width: 700}}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Search" variant="outlined"/>}
     />
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar scenario using Autocomplete/Textfield in a Search/Nav bar.   The value would always be left behind after using a `history.push` or other Router function in the onChange event.   The trick is to set the `inputValue = ""` .  Every time the component renders, the previous value will be removed.   See below

```
<Autocomplete
  {...defaultProps}
  onChange={(event, value) => {
    if(value) 
      router.history.push(`/summary`);
  }}
  filterOptions={filterOptions}
  clearOnEscape={true}
  inputValue=""
  renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} 
                                    label="Quick Search"  fullWidth                            
                                    InputProps={{...params.InputProps, 
                                      'aria-label': 'description',
                                                disableUnderline: true, 
                           }}/>}
/>
```

Comment: Well, this does not work for me. It just makes the text field stop accepting any input, since the input text is not forwarded to the input element

Answer (score -2):

yo! I'm pretty sure the Textfield component from material takes an "autoComplete" prop, and you can pass that the string "false". Also, it does not go in inputProps, try that out.

```
<Textfield autoComplete="false" />
```

Comment: You are probably referring to the browsers auto-complete. My use case requires the usage of a more robust option where I can pick the options presented.

Answer (score -4):

I had the same issue and I solved it with this :

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
```

Then you don't need to use refs.